# Synchronizing data in a file and a heap by deleting values from a heap and inserting values into a heap

Tags: c, file, tree, heap, insertion

You write in this file on the first line, a **m** number, representing the number of nodes the heap can have and on the next **m** lines, either 1 or 2 and next to it, a specified number to use in the tree.

You have 2 operations(1 and 2):
1 is to add an element and 2 to delete the biggest one and show it.

So basically, the insertion function is tied with the heap function to insert the digit at the end and put it at front afterwards.

Also, the deletetion function with heapify is switching the first and the last number and then, deleting the last number(which is now the first), but also you need to print it in another file.

In the **pla.txt** file, you have something like:

```
12
1 18
1 12
1 3
2
1 3
1 15
2
2
1 8
2
1 19
2
```

12 represents the number of nodes, then if we read **1** it will do the insertion and if we read **2** it will do the deletion. My problem is that it doesn't work, it shows addresses only, in place of showing the biggest numbers. (The number 2 operation deletes the biggest number deleted in the heap, so it will input in the file "cur.txt", `18,15,12,8,19`)
What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap1(int c,int b)
{
    int aux=c;
    c=b;
    b=aux;
}FILE *g=fopen("cur.txt","w");
void heapify(int a[],int index,int m)
{
    int leftindex=2*index;
    int rightindex=2*index+1;
    int father=index;
    if(leftindex<m&&leftindex>0 && a[leftindex]>a[father])
    {
        father=leftindex;
    }
    if(rightindex<m && rightindex>0&& a[rightindex]>a[father])
    {
        father=rightindex;
    }
    if(father!=index)
    {
        swap1(a[index],a[father] );
        heapify(a,father,m-1);
    }   
}
void heap(int a[], int index)
{
    int parent=(index-1)/2;
    if(a[index]>a[parent] && a[parent]>0)
    {
        swap1(a[index],a[parent]);
        heap(a,parent);
    }
}   

void insertion(int a[],int x,int  m)
{   
        m++;
        a[m-1]=x;
        heap(a,m-1);
}
void deletetion(int a[],int m)
{
    a[1]=a[m-1];
    m=m-1;  
    heapify(a,1,m); 
    fprintf(g,"%d ",a[1]);

}
int main()
{   
    FILE *f=fopen("pla.txt","r");
    int m;
    fscanf(f,"%d",&m);
    int op,x;
    int a[m];
    int z=1;
    while(fscanf(f,"%d",&op)!=EOF)
    {
        if(op==1)
        {
            fscanf(f,"%d",&x);
            insertion(a,x,z);
        }
        else 
        {
            deletetion(a,z);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `swap1` function doesn't work, at least not work as you seem to expect it to work. It won't swap the values/variables you use when calling the function. In C all arguments are passed *by value*, which means the values are *copied* and the function only have local copies of the values. Do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: I've tried to put it as pointers in swap and to put all the swaps with &

Comment: But I'll read about what you said

Comment: I don't think that was the only wrong thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `fprintf(g,"%d ",&a[1]);` to `fprintf(g,"%d ",a[1]);` in **deletetion** function.

And there are some more potential errors.
The main problem is that you didn't use pointer in functions.
Because C does not support parameter by reference.
So you need use pointer in **swap** function and also use pointer for parameter **m** for **heapify**, **insertion** and **deletion** functions.

Comment: oh right, but it seems it's still not working  idk why

Comment: Yeah, I added fixes for some more bugs.

Comment: oh, let me try that

Comment: I've added & for insertion, deletion and made swap with pointers, it shows like `12 12 3 3 3 ` , which is for some reason wrong

Comment: Thanks aswell for all the effort!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap1(int *c,int *b)
{
    int aux=*c;
    *c=*b;
    *b=aux;
}FILE *g=fopen("cur.txt","w");
void heapify(int a[],int index,int m)
{
    int leftindex=2*index; //=2
    int rightindex=2*index+1; //=3
    int father=index;
    if(leftindex<=m && leftindex>0 && a[leftindex]>a[father])
    {
        father=leftindex;
    }
    if(rightindex<=m && rightindex>0&& a[rightindex]>a[father])
    {
        father=rightindex;
    }
    if(father!=index)
    {
        swap1(&a[index],&a[father] );
        heapify(a,father,m);
    }   
}
void heap(int a[], int index)
{
    int parent=index/2;
    if(a[index]>a[parent] && a[parent]>0)
    {
        swap1(&a[index],&a[parent]);
        heap(a,parent);
    }
}   

void insertion(int a[],int x,int &m)
{   

        a[m]=x;
        heap(a,m);
        m++; 
}
void deletetion(int a[],int &m)
{
    //first time m=4;
    fprintf(g,"%d ",a[1]);
    a[1]=a[m-1];
    m=m-1;  
    heapify(a,1,m); 

}
int main()
{   
    FILE *f=fopen("pla.txt","r");
    int q;
    fscanf(f,"%d",&q);
    int op,x;
    int a[q];
    for(op=1;op<=q;op++)
    {
        a[op]=0;
    }
    int z=1;
    while(fscanf(f,"%d",&op)!=EOF)
    {
        if(op==1)
        {
            fscanf(f,"%d",&x);
            insertion(a,x,z);
        }
        else if(op==2)
        {
            deletetion(a,z);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, it was both the pointers, but also I made some mistakes about the array positioning and function logic, now it works perfectly!